# Anyone know how to reset sprockets or the asset pipeline in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, sprockets

I just deployed some code my remote, but its cached on the old css inside of `all.css`. I would like to just recompile it. I tried `rm all.css` , but that doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Increment assets version in your config. 
Please share your rails version for a better answer.

When a new rails app is created,the

```
config.assets.version= '1.0'
```

configuration setting is created. To force assets recompilation, increment this number.
This setting should be available starting from Rails 3.1.